Word and phrase hints to boost Google Speech-to-Text API accuracy
Our voice bots use Google Speech-to-Text API. The bots need to recognize answers in English from people leaving in Cyprus. We faced an issue with poor accuracy of Cyprus cities recognition (Limassol, Paphos, etc.).
In the article below there is the following statement:
'Use word and phrase hints to add names and terms to the vocabulary and to boost the accuracy for specific words and phrases.'
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices-provide-speech-data
Please advise what specific word and phrase hints are available for Speech-to-Text API users to improve the speech recognition accuracy?
I tried to find recommendations in the Google Documentation. The only way to enrich Google's vocabulary was found here
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-console
